# Flot: Impossible to remove point shadow

Tags: javascript, flot, shadow

I cannot remove the shadow when I plot points of different sizes and colors with javascript flot library.

```
$(function () {

  var d2 = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3],[4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7],[8, 8], [9, 9], [10, 10], [11, 11]];
  var colors = ["#cc4444", "#ff0000", "#0000ff", "#00ff00"];
  var radius = [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
  var rainbow = new Rainbow();
  rainbow.setSpectrum('blue','green', 'yellow','red');
  rainbow.setNumberRange(1, 12); 

  function raw(plot, ctx) {
    var data = plot.getData();
    var axes = plot.getAxes();
    var offset = plot.getPlotOffset();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var series = data[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < series.data.length; j++) {
            var color = colors[j];
            var d = (series.data[j]);
            var x = offset.left + axes.xaxis.p2c(d[0]);
            var y = offset.top + axes.yaxis.p2c(d[1]);
            var r = radius[j];                
            ctx.lineWidth = 0;
            ctx.shadowSize=0;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
            ctx.closePath();            
            ctx.fillStyle = "#"+rainbow.colourAt(r);
            ctx.fill();


        }    
    }
  };  
    var plot = $.plot(
          $("#placeholder"),

          [{ data: d2, points: { show: true ,shadowSize:0,lineWidth: 0}}],
          { hooks: { draw  : [raw] }}
  );  
});
```

I tried to set different shadowSize but it is not working while lineWidth works properly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shadowSize` is not a property of the `points` object.

You need to specify `shadowSize` in the `series` object:

```
[{ 
    data: d2, 
    points:
    { 
        show: true,
        lineWidth: 0
    },
    shadowSize: 0
}]
```

[Flot API Data Format Section](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format)

Comment: @IdreesSamim If an answer solves your problem, you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it (click the checkmark to the left).